# Having trouble in building Rpackage using R/C++ functions

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, r-package

I have a C++ function that is called inside an R function using Rcpp packgae. The R function accepts an `inputDataFrame` and uses the C++ function (also accepts a DataFrame) to calculate drug amounts `(A1)` as a function with time. R then returns the `inputDataFrame` with added column for the calculated amounts `A1`.

I have trouble making an Rpackage for this function. I followed [RStudio instruction](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-package.pdf) but I ran into an error when building the package. The error is in the `RcppExport.cpp` file and states that `'OneCompIVbolusCpp' was not declared in this scope`.

Here are the codes for the C++ and R functions. They work perfectly fine in R when I process an example dataframe.

Rfunction `OneCompIVbolus_Rfunction.R`:

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("OneCompIVbolusCppfunction.cpp")

OneCompIVbolusRCpp <- function(inputDataFrame){

  inputDataFrame$A1[inputDataFrame$TIME==0] <- inputDataFrame$AMT[inputDataFrame$TIME==0]
  OneCompIVbolusCpp( inputDataFrame )

  inputDataFrame
}
```

C++ function `OneCompIVbolusCppfunction.cpp`:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
// input Dataframe from R
DataFrame OneCompIVbolusCpp(DataFrame inputFrame){

  //  Create vectors of each element used in function and for constructing output dataframe
  Rcpp::DoubleVector TIME = inputFrame["TIME"];
  Rcpp::DoubleVector AMT = inputFrame["AMT"];
  Rcpp::DoubleVector k10 = inputFrame["k10"];
  Rcpp::DoubleVector A1 = inputFrame["A1"];

  double currentk10, currentTime, previousA1, currentA1;

  // in C++ arrays start at index 0, so to start at 2nd row need to set counter to 1
  // for counter from 1 to the number of rows in input data frame
  for(int counter = 1; counter < inputFrame.nrows(); counter++){
  // pull out all the variables that will be used for calculation
    currentk10  = k10[ counter ];
    currentTime = TIME[ counter ] - TIME[ counter - 1];
    previousA1  = A1[ counter - 1 ];

    // Calculate currentA1
    currentA1 = previousA1*exp(-currentTime*currentk10);

    // Fill in Amounts and check for other doses
    A1[ counter ] = currentA1 + AMT[ counter ];

  } // end for loop
  return(0);
}
```

Any hints on what am I doing wrong here? How may I solve this issue?

**Edit**:

Here is an example of running the composite function `OneCompIVbolusRCpp` in R:

```
library(plyr)
library(Rcpp)

source("OneCompIVbolus_Rfunction.R")

#-------------
# Generate df 
#-------------
#Set dose records:
dosetimes <- c(0,12)
#set number of subjects
ID <- 1:2
#Make dataframe
df <- expand.grid("ID"=ID,"TIME"=sort(unique(c(seq(0,24,1),dosetimes))),"AMT"=0,"MDV"=0,"CL"=2,"V"=10)
doserows <- subset(df, TIME%in%dosetimes)
#Dose = 100 mg, Dose 1  at time 0
doserows$AMT[doserows$TIME==dosetimes[1]] <- 100
#Dose 2 at 12
doserows$AMT[doserows$TIME==dosetimes[2]] <- 50
#Add back dose information
df <- rbind(df,doserows)
df <- df[order(df$ID,df$TIME,df$AMT),]       # arrange df by TIME (ascending) and by AMT (descending)
df <- subset(df, (TIME==0 & AMT==0)==F) # remove the row that has a TIME=0 and AMT=0
df$k10 <- df$CL/df$V
#-------------
# Apply the function 
#-------------
simdf <- ddply(df, .(ID), OneCompIVbolusRCpp)
```

Comment: github link to the package, mebbe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply have the wrong ordering. Instead of

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
// input Dataframe from R
DataFrame OneCompIVbolusCpp(DataFrame inputFrame){
   // ...
```

do

```
// input Dataframe from R
// [[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame OneCompIVbolusCpp(DataFrame inputFrame){
   // ...
```

as the `[[Rcpp::export]]` tag **must** come directly before the function it exports.

Comment: Yep! thank you! I have another question if possible. It doesn't seem that I can use the `roxygen2` package for R packages that uses Rcpp? It didn't work with me but I works fine when I have my function as `*.R` files?

Comment: Yes you can!  Add roxygen2 stuff to the C++ function,  this will get carried into the R file where roxygen2 takes over?

Comment: I tried adding some roxygen comment in the Cpp function code but it didn't work. Properly missing something?

Comment: Here is something I committed [just today](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppapt/blob/master/src/buildDepends.cpp#L30-L47).